# Team of travelling salesmen.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

A team of salesmen from a company go on tour and market / sell one of their products

1. They start from the same town $a$
2. When they are done they meet in the same town $b$.
3. A list of towns shall have been visited by at least one salesman.

**We know:**

1. The costs and time to travel between each pair of towns to be visited (incl. $a$ and $b$).
2. The cost of each salesman's time.

We want to minimize the

1. Cost of travel for all salesmen.
2. Total idle time cost. I.e. the cost of the sum of time each traveller has to wait at $b$ for the last salesman to arrive.

Can we formulate this as an optimization problem?

Comment: Do you want to minimize the sum of 1+2? There is probably a tradeoff between 1 and 2, so minimizing both seems impossible. How can you figure out the idle time of a specific traveler? Maybe you also have a travel time for each pair of towns?

Comment: Part of the question is about trying to figure out if it has to be a tradeoff or not. The idle time of a specific traveller is the time from he arrives until the last of the travellers arrive. Yes you are right, both a cost and a time for each pair of towns.

Comment: Hmm I suppose I meant the overall cost is to be minimized as the idle time costs money (pay them while they have nothing to do but sit and wait).

Comment: So as long as a salesman is traveling, this is not idle time, even if he only visits towns that already have been visited? For me, it would make more sense to minimize "total travel cost + total time spent".
Also, no matter how you formulate this, it already *is* an optimization problem: Minimize something subject to some constraints.